# Lumen whereRaw with Prepared Statement Returns Nothing

Tags: php, mysql, lumen

I'm trying to get the value from the database with this query

```
$vouchers = MerchantVoucher::where([
            'merchant_id' => $this->merchant->id,
            'code' => $voucherCode
        ])
        ->whereRaw("
            (
                (valid_from between '{$voucherValidFrom}' and '{$voucherValidTo}' ) || 
                (valid_to between '{$voucherValidFrom}' and '{$voucherValidTo}')
            )"
        )
        ->count();
```

with this query i got the expected result which it returns one for the number of rows.
I tried to Optimize the query using Prepared Statement for this query belows

```
    $vouchers = MerchantVoucher::where([
        'merchant_id' => $this->merchant->id,
        'code' => $voucherCode
    ])
    ->whereRaw("
        ( 
            (valid_from between '?' and '?' ) || 
            (valid_to between '?' and '?' ) 
        )", 
        [
            $voucherValidFrom, 
            $voucherValidTo, 
            $voucherValidFrom, 
            $voucherValidTo
        ]
    )
    ->count();
```

when I use this query it returns 0.

Anyone got explanation for this? thank you in Advance!

Raw Sql Comparison for non PHP user

```
 select count(*) from `merchant_vouchers` where (`merchant_id` = ? and `code` = ?) and 
                (
                    (valid_from between '2019-12-03 11:36:35' and '2019-12-10 11:36:35' ) || 
                    (valid_to between '2019-12-03 11:36:35' and '2019-12-10 11:36:35')
                ) and `merchant_vouchers`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Returns 1

```
  select count(*) from `merchant_vouchers` where (`merchant_id` = ? and `code` = ?) and 
                ( 
                    (valid_from between '?' and '?' ) || 
                    (valid_to between '?' and '?' ) 
                ) and 
                `merchant_vouchers`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Returns 0

Framework used : Lumen

Database : MySQL

Comment: Can't verify my assumption right now, but I think you need to remove the quotes around the identifiers: `valid_from between ? and ?`

Comment: @Fitzi well your assumption solved my problem :), Thank you!

Comment: I'll make it an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes around your placeholders:
`valid_from between ? and ?`